# How to suppress all autograph warnings from Tensorflow?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

I'm getting a warning which I cannot find a solution to.
Apparently this:

```py
import os
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '2'  # or any {'0', '1', '2'}
import tensorflow as tf
os.environ['AUTOGRAPH_VERBOSITY'] = '1'
```

is not enough to stop this annoying message:

```py
WARNING:tensorflow:AutoGraph could not transform <function Model.make_train_function.<locals>.train_function at 0x00000281A55264C8> and will run it as-is.
Please report this to the TensorFlow team. When filing the bug, set the verbosity to 10 (on Linux, `export AUTOGRAPH_VERBOSITY=10`) and attach the full output.
Cause: Bad argument number for Name: 4, expecting 3
To silence this warning, decorate the function with @tf.autograph.experimental.do_not_convert
```

which pops up after every single epoch.

And yes, I've decorated every function I have with `@tf.autograph.experimental.do_not_convert` and the message still pops up. I am currently using Tensorflow 2.2.0

If you know the reason why this is happening, that would be great. I have no clue what "Name" is, as nothing is called that anywhere in any of my files.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this:

```
tf.autograph.set_verbosity(0)
```

If that doesn't work, perhaps the `logging` module could be of help here:

```
import logging
logging.getLogger("tensorflow").setLevel(logging.ERROR) # this goes *before* tf import
import tensorflow as tf
```

Thanks @Shahrokh Bah for adding that comment.

Comment: tensorflow 2.6.2: Option #2 works. Option #1 not working.

Comment: The key point is to place `logging.getLogger("tensorflow").setLevel(logging.ERROR)` before `import tensorflow as tf`. That way, it will silent the warning about Autograph.